# Date formatting from Google Spreadsheet to Telegram bot

Tags: javascript

I make a bot which is connected with spreadsheets with Webhook.

I have a cell with a date formatted like `'dd MMMM'`, e.g. `"03 september"`. It is got from a certain amount of milliseconds which is equal to 03.09.2020 00:00:00 GMT+3.
I want to use this exact value (`"03 september"`) as a poll option.

You can see my code below.

If I use it as it is, poll option is somehow converted into the value
`"2020-09-02T21:00:00.000"`. If I map all the dates into Strings before sending it into JSON then this option looks like `"Thu Sep 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 ... "`.
How can I keep it looking simple in telegram?

**UPD:** I figured that `Utilities.formatDate()` is a proper solution for this, but still I don't know how to format month name into russian locale.

```js
function doWork() {
  var availableDates = scheduleSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5).getValues()[0];
  //var stringDates = availableDates.map(function(date) {return String(date)});
  sendPoll(chatId, availableDates);
}

function sendPoll(chatId, options) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendPoll",
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      question: "Some question:",
      options: JSON.stringify(options),
      is_anonymous: false,
      allows_multiple_answers: true,
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(REMOVE_KEYBOARD)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}
```

Comment: I thought that in your situation, to use `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()` might be suitable. So how about modifying from `var availableDates = scheduleSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5).getValues()[0];` to `var availableDates = scheduleSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5).getDisplayValues()[0];`?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) suggested, in order to keep the displayed formats when retrieving dates (or any value) from sheet cells in Apps Script, use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues):

> Returns a two-dimensional array of displayed values, indexed by row, then by column. The values are String objects. **The displayed value takes into account date, time and currency formatting, including formats applied automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting**.